# Allow attachments in Yammer embed

Tags: embed, attachment, yammer

I am using the embed script provided here in Sharepoint 2013 Online: https://developer.yammer.com/connect/. It works great and I like it better than the Yammer app you can embed because it renders more quickly and I can specify the group I want to show on the page.

BUT, there is no paper clip / attachment icon. People have to go to "full Yammer" if they want to attach an image or file, which is something our users do very often.

Is there something that can be added to the script which will allow them to attach?

Answer (score 3):

There are technical/product reasons why we haven't supported attachments in Embed to-date.

1) There are 3 options to attach a file/note when you click the paperclip in the web product.  Because Yammer Embed runs in an iframe, two of those options (the ones with the lightbox) are not able to render for the user.

2) With IE8/IE9 attaching files through iframes causes CORS conflicts, especially when you involve trusted sites/zones.

We're specing out new features in Embed now, and I'll bring up your idea to the team again to revisit if we can accomplish this in the future.